# Silva Connect Pedometer custom USB log reader application

Tags: .net, connection, usb, arrays, byte

I bought a Silva Pedometer EX Connect in December which looks like 
[this](http://www.google.hu/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=silva+pedometer+ex+30&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&docid=cPo96khseLZ8yM&tbnid=Ly11vK0dizh9tM%3a&ved=0CAUQjRw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cyclesportsuk.co.uk%2Fproduct_info.php%3Fproducts_id%3D11460&ei=n083UdC4IYXdOteIgcAH&bvm=bv.43287494,d.d2k&psig=AFQjCNHjrvdnv3svB4qiZMHEoveW1GZz_g&ust=1362665751142248)
The problem that I didn't know that in this month Silva discontinued this product and their site called silveconnect.com. This site could read my steps for 30 previos steps via thei little application. They offered me to send them this item and they'll send be back a newer but I don't like it and has only 5-7days memory.

So I decided to make an application for custom use to read its memory because I recently forgot to write down the current steps for that day and at midnight it changes back to 0 but the internal memory stores the last 30 days. The little webapp isn't available now but I stored on my PC. It needed .net framework 2 so it is some like .net application. Because site is unavailable it's no longer working.

My question is that is there any app that can tell me what kind of data and bytes transferring through the USB cable? Or can I decompile this 400K exe application? I'm a flash dev and UI dev so .net is not my business, but its not too complicated. ;)  So the first step is dark to me.

Any help would appreciated. thanky
George

Answer (score 0):

You can Decompile the .exe using [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) if it was programmed in .NET

And if that doesn't work for you and you want to get dirty with USB data, 
you can use [LibUSBdotnet](http://libusbdotnet.sourceforge.net/V2/Index.html) (good luck!)